# How to use a GraphQL hook in a base app component in react without re-rendering?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, graphql, react-hooks, react-lifecycle-hooks

I am trying to use redux with GraphQL  `const sliceQuery = useQuery(ALL_SLICES)` on React but it seems as if i cant use useEffect to minimize renders due to GraphQL hooks and their promise `Object { data: {}, variables: {}, refetch: (), fetchMore: (), updateQuery: (), startPolling: (), stopPolling: (), subscribeToMore: (), loading: true, networkStatus: 1, … }`. So instead i am forced to update `props.slices` outside of a useEffect since i have to wait for the GraphQL hook to finish loading with the following:

```
if (!sliceQuery.loading && props.slices === null) {
  const allSlices = sliceQuery.data.allSlices
  props.initializeSlices(allSlices)
  props.setCurrentSlice(allSlices.find(s => s._id === splitUrl[5]))
}
```

Here is my full App.js component:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { initializeSlices } from './reducers/sliceReducer'
import { setCurrentSlice } from './reducers/currentSliceReducer'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useQuery } from '@apollo/react-hooks'
import NavBar from './components/navBar/NavBar'
import Slice from './components/pages/Slice'
import About from './components/pages/About'
import Policies from './components/pages/Policies'
import Contact from './components/pages/Contact'
import './static/css/base.css'
import { ALL_SLICES } from './schemas'

const App = (props) => {
  console.log('App.js is ran')
  const sliceQuery = useQuery(ALL_SLICES)
  const splitUrl = window.location.href.split('/')
  if (!sliceQuery.loading && props.slices === null) {
    const allSlices = sliceQuery.data.allSlices
    props.initializeSlices(allSlices)
    props.setCurrentSlice(allSlices.find(s => s._id === splitUrl[5]))
  }

  const getSliceById = (id) => {
    return props.slices.find(s => s._id === id)
  }

  if (!props.slices || !props.currentSlice) {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>loading..</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <Router>
        <NavBar />
        <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Slice slice={getSliceById('5e2db26efa3d070ec879b0e9')} /> } />
        <Route path="/slice/:name/:id" render={({match}) => <Slice slice={getSliceById(match.params.id)} /> } />
        <Route path="/about" render={() => <About /> } />
        <Route path="/policies" render={() => <Policies /> } />
        <Route path="/contact" render={() => <Contact /> } />
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    slices: state.slices,
    currentSlice: state.currentSlice,
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { initializeSlices, setCurrentSlice }
)(App)
```

Here is the console log of just the page loading:

> The development server has disconnected.
>   Refresh the page if necessary.
>
> [HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...
>
> App.js is ran
>
> ./src/App.js
>     Line 1:17:  'useEffect' is defined but never used  no-unused-va
>
> Warning: Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; triggering nested component updates from render is not allowed. If necessary, trigger nested updates in componentDidUpdate.
>   Check the render method of App.
>
> App.js is ran
>
> App.js is ran
>
> App.js is ran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still use `useEffect` to only execute your methods when your data becomes available.

```
const allSlices = 
    !sliceQuery.loading && props.slices === null 
        ? sliceQuery.data.allSlices 
        : null;

useEffect(() => {
    if(allSlices !== null) {
        props.initializeSlices(allSlices)
        props.setCurrentSlice(allSlices.find(s => s._id === splitUrl[5]))
    }
}, [allSlices, props.initializeSlices, props.setCurrentSlice])
```

This will only call the methods `props.initializeSlices` and `props.setCurrentSlice` when `allSlices` becomes available.

If these methods are also created at render time, you may need to use `useCallback` where they are created to stop them triggering the `useEffect` hook to execute on subsquent renders.

Comment: Thank you very much this cleared my primary error concerning nested component updates but unfortunately the page continues to re-render multiple times. How would you propose I implement `useCallback` to reduce the amount of App.js re-renders? Thank you in advance